# Page.Request.QueryString has a value although none was passed to the page

Tags: .net, sharepoint, request.querystring

We have the following code that is returning a value of "3" although no value is passed as a query string.  Is there some way that the "id" is getting stuck in the server memory (since it is not user specific) or is "id" a special value.  Any ideas?

```
if (Page.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
{
Page.Trace.Write("Query String Key Found");
ListItemID = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"];
}
```

This is in a SharePoint 2007 webpart.

Answer (score 0):

If the webpart is on page that was navigated to by clicking a list item from the previous page; you'd be seeing the id of that list item.

Answer (score 0):

There probably is a post (or GET) with parameters somewhere, that's hidden from you. Querystrings are the GET variables that are past along and there is no "stuck" or "server memory".

Use a tool like [HTTPAnalyzer](http://www.ieinspector.com/httpanalyzer/) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to analyze the HTTP traffic. That will show you who's making what requests. 
Although it's probably the ID of the control you're clicking on since you're in Sharepoint.

Comment: When I clear all my cache, and open a new browser and navigate to the aspx page the querystring have a value even though I am specifically putting the URL in by hand.

Comment: Where does the code reside? Is it in the main page? Or is it in a control that's referenced from the page? If it's in a control that's referenced from the page do a "View Source" on your HTML and see the URL to your component. There has to be an "id" parameter in that URL.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the browser cache.

Comment: The browser cache has nothing to do with the HttpRequest

Comment: @Mircea, I know that. But a full browser cache can cause all kinds of voodoo, especially when working on Web Parts in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when a webpart gets added, all parameters that it has available for input get assigned a default value, for instance, add a dataformwebpart to an ampty page and bind it to a list. Then open the source of the page. You see a bunch of parameterbindings there, which in turn can be bound to querystrings. Could you if your webpart got assigned a default value for ListItemId?

Or are you actually debugging and stepping into this particular piece of code and the id querystring variable actually contains 3? If so, I agree with one of the other answers, use Fiddler to check how many http calls are made when you open the page.